JSON Data validation from JSON Schema using java
I am using this dependency implementation("org.everit.json:org.everit.json.schema:1.51") for generating and validating JSON schema using java code
    schemaJson = new JSONObject(jsonSchema);
    Schema schema = schemaLoader.load(schemaJson);
    JSONObject obj1 = new JSONObject(modelInstance.getModelData());
    schema.validate(obj1);

If the jsonSchema looks like this
{
  "allOf": [
    {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "CommonField1": {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "Relation": {
              "enum": [
                "<=",
                ">="
              ]
            },
            "Value": {
              "enum": [
                "M(Million)",
                "K(Thousand)"
              ]
            },
            "Unit": {
              "type": "string"
            }
          },
          "required": [
            "Relation",
            "Value",
            "Unit"
          ]
        },
        "Name": {
          "$ref": "#/properties/CommonField1"
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "CommonField1",
        "Name"
      ]
    }
  ]
}

while validating it with JSON data, it is giving error #key[properties] not found.
